# Detecting when textarea scroll has reached the bottom to enable button

Tags: textarea, scroll, detect

I want to display a license agreement in a scrolling textarea and detect when the user has scrolled to the bottom of  the text area, then enable the submit button.
Is there a way to do that?

Answer (score 1):

[Here's](http://www.27seconds.com/kb/article_view.aspx?id=56) an implementation in javascript. The core functionality is:

```
function textareaAtEnd(area)
{
    return ((area.scrollTop + area.offsetHeight) > area.scrollHeight);
}
```

Comment: Why `>` instead of `=` or `>=`? After all, can you scroll past the end?

Comment: Link is dead, here is an archived copy of the page http://web.archive.org/web/20080207192604/https://www.27seconds.com/kb/article_view.aspx?id=56